# ScrollView does not scroll to the Bottom in android

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I know this question has been asked many times over here, but none of the solutions have helped me. I did try changing the margins to padding, it does scroll then, but then I am unable to position the buttons in a proper manner. 
Here is the xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/about_us_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/about_us_toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/about_us_udaan_chakali"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/udaan_wing"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/about_us_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Udaan"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/about_us_udaan_chakali"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/about_us_description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. "
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/about_us_title"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/about_us_connect"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Connect with us"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/about_us_description"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/about_us_connect"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mail"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.21"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/email" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/facebook"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/mail"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mail"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/facebook_box" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/youtube"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/facebook"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/facebook"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/youtube_play" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/playstore"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mail"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/googleplay"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/mail"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/mail" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/website"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/playstore"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/playstore"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/web_link"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/facebook"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/facebook" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/youtube"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/website"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/youtube"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/website"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/phone"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/about_us_reach"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Reach Us"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/website"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_reach"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/about_us_reach"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/map_view"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_reach"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/google_maps" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="BVM Engineering College, Opp, Shastri Maidan, Mota Bazaar, Vallabh Vidhyanagar, Anand, Gujarat 388120, India"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/map_view"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carefully observe your Toolbar code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/about_us_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Output 1:

[image]

---

Look at the 4 constraints on the Toolbar:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

This would cause the Toolbar to be centred inside the parent. And since the scroll view is constrained to be below the toolbar, it cannot scroll all it's contents after the top of the scroll touches the top toolbar.

Remove this constraint:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Now your new Toolbar code would be:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/about_us_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Output 2:

[image]

Comment: in your example you still have         `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` but you said to remove it.. anyway it didn't help me anyway and I didn't have this constraint for toolbar, for toolbar I just used width match_parent and height wrap_content and still could not scroll to bottom

Comment: to fix I just had to replace ConstraintLayout with LinearLayout, and only ScrollView has child ConstraintLayout, so only one ConstraintLayout no two, seems like Android Bug when it doesn't work with `ConstraintLayout > ScrollView > ConstraintLayout` correctly